# java - referencing elements in an arraylist whilst removing some

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, stack

I have a for loop looping through each element in an arrayList performing someMethod() on them, depending on the result of that method I either want to keep or remove that element from the list. for example:

```
int returnResult;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    returnResult = someMethod(arrayList.get(i));
    if (returnResult == -1){
        arrayList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

My question is; if i have say 5 elements in the list and on the second iteration through the loop (so when i=1), I remove that element, when I go through the 3rd iteration will arrayList.get(2) be referencing what was actually the 4th element? i.e. does it immediately reduce the stack size?

Comment: yes, it reduce the size when you call `remove(...)` method. And your program will end unexpectedly, but actually it is the expected result.

Comment: awesome thank you, do you know if there is a way round this?

Comment: It would be nice if there is something like a documentation for every common method .... oh here it is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. In order to get around this, you can iterate through the array in reverse.

```
int returnResult;
for (int i=3;i>=0;i--){
    returnResult = someMethod(arrayList.get(i));
    if (returnResult == -1){
        arrayList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

This pops them off from the end, and doesn't affect the elements left to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this :

```
int returnResult, limit = 4;
for (int i=0; i < limit; i++){
    returnResult = someMethod(arrayList.get(i));
    if (returnResult == -1){
        arrayList.remove(i);
        limit--;
    }
}
```